# .NET Regular Expression - Create string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression which I use to extract two portions of a folder name:

```
([0-9]{8})_([0-9A-Ba-c]+)_BLAH
```

No problems. This will match 12345678_abc_BLAH - I have "12345678" and "abc" in two groups.

Is it possible to construct the folder name by supplying a method with two strings and inserting them into the groups of the pattern?

```
public string ConstructFolderName(string firstGroup, string secondGroup, string pattern)
{

    //Return firstGroup_secondGroup_BLAH

}
```

This would be more manageable using same pattern to extract groups and construct strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your regex will always have two capturing groups, then you can regex the regex, so to speak.

```
private Regex captures = new Regex(@"\(.+?\)");

public string ConstructFolderName(string firstGroup, string secondGroup, string pattern)
{
    MatchCollection matches = captures.Matches(pattern);

    return pattern.Replace(matches[0].Value, firstGroup).Replace(matches[1].Value, secondGroup);
}
```

Obviously this doesn't have any error checking and might be better done with some other method than String.Replace; but, this certainly works and should give you some ideas.

**EDIT**: An obvious improvement would be to actually use the pattern to validate the `firstGroup` and `secondGroup` strings before you construct them. The `MatchCollection`'s 0 and 1 item could create their own Regex and perform a match there. I can add that if you want.

**EDIT2**: Here's the validation I was talking about:

```
private Regex captures = new Regex(@"\(.+?\)");

public string ConstructFolderName(string firstGroup, string secondGroup, string pattern)
{
    MatchCollection matches = captures.Matches(pattern);

    Regex firstCapture = new Regex(matches[0].Value);

    if (!firstCapture.IsMatch(firstGroup))
        throw new FormatException("firstGroup");

    Regex secondCapture = new Regex(matches[1].Value);

    if (!secondCapture.IsMatch(secondGroup))
        throw new FormatException("secondGroup");

    return pattern.Replace(firstCapture.ToString(), firstGroup).Replace(secondCapture.ToString(), secondGroup);
}
```

Also, I might add that you can change the second capturing group to `([0-9ABa-c]+)` since A to B isn't really a range.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is perfect. I knew it would never be the most elegant solution but it solves the problem of the pattern being managed in separate locations.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking to use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?

[String.Format Method (String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah, so I have overlooked something obvious! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just to be clear. Can I do something like String.Format(pattern, firstGroupValue, secondGroupValue)? I want to use ([0-9]{8})_([0-9A-Ba-c]+)_BLAH as the pattern. This sits in a config file and I want it to remain as a single setting.

Comment: Okay, I feel like I am on the cusp of a solution. Any ideas?